# android setTextSize different behavior

Tags: android

I've this situation

```
<dimen name="fld_label_size">22sp</dimen>
<dimen name="fld_stat_size">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="question_fld_label_size_text">24sp</dimen>
```

in my dimension file

then in a activity

```
lblEnd.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.question_fld_label_size_text));
```

in other activity inside a table layout

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2f);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(percent);
    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(lp1);

    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fld_stat_size));
```

the first you see correctly the second is so small that the characters are not even distinguish

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I try to put code in LinearLayout and not in table. The result is different. I see textView as I expected

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.survey);
TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
tv0.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fld_stat_size));
tv0.setText(c.getString(0));

tv0.setId(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("txtView_"+c.getString(5),null,null));
tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv0.setPadding(0,150,0,0);
rl.addView(tv0);
```

Comment: Try TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP instead of TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX.

Comment: I try it. At 12sp text is invisible. On 14sp text is too big. I can see only two text view over 54.

Comment: in first, you are using `question_fld_label_size_text` it's not listed in dimen sample that you posted, is it possible it's some other (higher) value ?

Comment: No. It's 24sp. There are some differences. In the first case I use a linear layout. In accordance with a table layout.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is clear, that you are using "fld_label_size" in first activity which is 22sp. And in second you are using "fld_stat_size", which is 12sp. It is recommended to use at least 14sp to make text distinguishable and clear.

Comment: 14sp is too big.